# firefox issues in ubuntu 13.04 64bit

Tags: 13.04, firefox, chown

First, im new in ubuntu so please bear with me.

My firefox used to be working normally for the first time i installed ubuntu 13.04. I dont feel did anything wrong, but it suddenly cant be opened via the launcher. When i tried to type "**firefox**" in the terminal, it shows the very same error like [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/306611/cant-open-firefox-after-upgrade-to-13-04) question.

So, i followed the answer in that question, and voila...its working now :D

However, something is still bothering me. Why is this happened suddenly? The fact that i used **chown** to make it works again means that the owner of the firefox is changed.

And why this message is still appearing in the terminal although the firefox is working now :  GLib-**CRITICAL **: g_slice_set_config: assertion `sys_page_size == 0' failed**

Thanks for your time :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That message always appears in the terminal when you open firefox, it's not a problem. I can't quite explain it, but it's a bit like when scammers trying to sell you so-called 'antivirus' in Windows they show you a program which contains a load of normal errors and say that it's not normal. Just forget about it. You probably opened it with root as `sudo` instead of `gksudo` some time by accident which would cause stuff to have different permissions.

Comment: Glad to hear it, Thanks :D So, its always safer to use gksudo when running GUI based program, is it true?

Comment: and the point is, sudo and gksudo could change the permission automatically right? I should be careful next time :D

Comment: Yes, that's exactly it. (first comment)